# Why can't reduction be used with OpenMP tasks?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp

This is the code for calculating a numerical approximation of the area of the Mandelbrot Set. I don't understand why can't I write `reduction(+ : numoutside)` instead of `shared(numoutside)` when declaring variables for the parallel region. When I do that, I get incorrect result. Can someone explain the problem with using reduction with OpenMP tasks, because it really confuses me why it doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define NPOINTS 2000
#define MAXITER 2000

struct complex
{
    double real;
    double imag;
};

int main()
{
    int i, j, iter, numoutside = 0;
    double area, error, ztemp;
    struct complex z, c;

    double time1, time2, elapsed;

    /*
     *
     *
     *     Outer loops run over npoints, initialise z=c
     *
     *     Inner loop has the iteration z=z*z+c, and threshold test
     */

    time1 = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel default(none) private(i, j, iter, c, z, ztemp) \
    shared(numoutside) // why not reduction(+ : numoutside) ???
    {
#pragma omp single
        {
            for (i = 0; i < NPOINTS; i++)
            {
#pragma omp task
                for (j = 0; j < NPOINTS; j++)
                {
                    // #pragma omp task - LOSE NE TREBA OVDE - NAPRAVICE SE PREVISE
                    // TASKOVA (NPOINTS * NPOINTS) I USPORICEMO SISTEM UMESTO DA UBRZAMO
                    {
                        c.real = -2.0 + 2.5 * (double)(i) / (double)(NPOINTS) + 1.0e-7;
                        c.imag = 1.125 * (double)(j) / (double)(NPOINTS) + 1.0e-7;
                        z = c;
                        for (iter = 0; iter < MAXITER; iter++)
                        {
                            ztemp = (z.real * z.real) - (z.imag * z.imag) + c.real;
                            z.imag = z.real * z.imag * 2 + c.imag;
                            z.real = ztemp;
                            if ((z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag) > 4.0e0)
                            {
#pragma omp atomic
                                numoutside++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    time2 = omp_get_wtime();
    elapsed = time2 - time1;
    printf("elapsed %f\n", elapsed);

    /*
     *  Calculate area and error and output the results
     */

    area = 2.0 * 2.5 * 1.125 * (double)(NPOINTS * NPOINTS - numoutside) / (double)(NPOINTS * NPOINTS);
    error = area / (double)NPOINTS;

    printf("Area of Mandlebrot set = %12.8f +/- %12.8f\n", area, error);
}
```

Comment: Why was it tagged C++? (to drive more attention?) There is no C++ here. It is tag spamming

Comment: No it is not an attempt at tag spamming. I didn't click C++ by mistake, but I am saying that I have mistakenly used tags C and C++ because I am used to those languages going together, like you always hear C/C++. Relax dude.

Comment: Why are you not using `pragma omp for` instead of tasks?

Comment: Because I am just practising OpenMP at the moment. I know that ```pragma omp for``` should be used, but I want to do it with tasks in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenMP task rules are a bit tricky. A variable that is `shared` in the enclosing OpenMP construct is by default still `shared` in the task, otherwise it is `firstprivate`.

What happens:

- `numoutside` is declared in a reduction clause, so the compiler create private instances of `numoutside` for each thread.
- Inside the `single` directive, only one of these instances is used.
- Because `numoutside` was not shared, it becomes `firstprivate` in each tasks: the compiler creates a fully new instance for each task. Whatever you doing on this instance within the task, it is lost once the task ends.
- At the end you get zero.

Note that declaring `numoutside` as shared will work only by chance if you don't protect the `numoutside++` instruction with an `atomic` directive.

I don't know how to perform reductions with the task contructs (I've seen that there exists a `task_reduction` clause in the OmpenMP standard, but I don't know how it works).

But actually, I wonder why you want to use tasks instead of a simple parallel loop...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "Why can't reduction be used with OpenMP tasks?" is "It can".
However, you have to write the code in a slightly different way.

Here's a marginally polished version of your code that does exactly that:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define NPOINTS 2000
#define MAXITER 2000

struct complex
{
    double real;
    double imag;
};

int main()
{
  /*
   *
   *
   *     Outer loops run over npoints, initialise z=c
   *
   *     Inner loop has the iteration z=z*z+c, and threshold test
   */

  double time1 = omp_get_wtime();
  int numoutside = 0;
 
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(numoutside) 
  {
#pragma omp single
    {
#pragma omp taskgroup task_reduction(+:numoutside)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < NPOINTS; i++)
          {
            #pragma omp task in_reduction(+:numoutside)
            {
              for (int j = 0; j < NPOINTS; j++)
                {
                  struct complex c;
                  c.real = -2.0 + 2.5 * (double)(i) / (double)(NPOINTS) + 1.0e-7;
                  c.imag = 1.125 * (double)(j) / (double)(NPOINTS) + 1.0e-7;
                  struct complex z = c;

                  for (int iter = 0; iter < MAXITER; iter++)
                    {
                      double ztemp = (z.real * z.real) - (z.imag * z.imag) + c.real;
                      z.imag = z.real * z.imag * 2 + c.imag;
                      z.real = ztemp;
                      if ((z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag) > 4.0e0)
                        {
                          numoutside++;
                          break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }

  double time2 = omp_get_wtime();
  double elapsed = time2 - time1;
  printf("elapsed %f\n", elapsed);

  /*
   *  Calculate area and error and output the results
   */

  double area = 2.0 * 2.5 * 1.125 * (double)(NPOINTS * NPOINTS - numoutside) / (double)(NPOINTS * NPOINTS);
  double error = area / (double)NPOINTS;

  printf("Area of Mandlebrot set = %12.8f +/- %12.8f\n", area, error);
}
```

I have cleaned the code up slightly by moving variable declarations to their minimal scope (something that was new in C99, so has only been available for over 20 years!). Doing that removes lots of noise in the OpenMP directives. I have also added the task reductions.

This code gives the same answer as your code and runs very marginally (~1%) faster than your code when using Clang 17.0.3 on my Mac M1 machine.